# How can I add the following functionalities to the Atom Editor?

Tags: package, coronasdk, atom-editor

I am used to using the following package for Sublime: https://github.com/coronalabs/CoronaSDK-SublimeText.

Especially, I would like Atom to have autocompletion, syntax highlighting, and the debugger.

What is the scope of trying to convert a package like this? Are there other packages for Atom with comparative functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what drives Atom, but Sublime Text's addon's are written in a language called Python. If Atom doesn't use a similar thing, I doubt you can duplicate it.